# Which android APIs should I use to create battery indicator line on status bar

Tags: java, android, android-animation, statusbar, indicator

I want to create a **battery indicator line** over the **status bar** to indicate the **usage of battery** in an android app.
What different android APIs should I be familiar with in order to get started.
The APIs i have been through in android developers guide are:

- Battery Manager
- Monitoring the battery level and Charge state

**P.S** This does not require Custom ROM or Rooting the device.

**Please help**.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Have a look at this:- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Comment: Yes sir @MuntaserAhmed ,AdarshYadav that is one of the many known api i have been through, but i dont know how a line can be drawn over the status bar.

Comment: @Hash : Have a look at this blog http://www.howtogeek.com/272459/how-to-customize-the-status-bar-on-android-without-rooting/

Comment: @Hash: Although above blog sounds interesting but still I don't think that we can do that without creating any custom ROM or rooted device.On other hand you have asked a very cool question, let me know if you will find any solution for it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about "battery and power management" APIs or are you asking about how to explicitly draw on the status bar?

Comment: Thanks @AdarshYadav but there are already many apps in the playstore which does that and most importantly it doesnt require any root or Custom ROM.

Comment: @selbie Actually both, i need to create a battery indicator in the form of translucent color bar on a status bar which indicates the battery level. please have a look at the image provided above, there is a translucent color line on status bar which shows the battery level.

Comment: You should really be asking two separate questions instead of a single question.  1) "What APIs are available to monitor battery state"  and 2) "How can I draw on top of the Android status bar"

Comment: @selbie thankyou for the suggestion, i'l take care while asking other queries properly the next time..Okay so can you answer me the 2nd question that you just asked.